# css: aspect ratio with grid-template

Tags: css

I am using the grid box in css. Each item in the grid must be 1/3 of the width of the container. I want the aspect ratio of each item to be 2/1 which means the width should always be twice as big as the height. If the size of the container resizes I want the items to resize as well while keeping the aspect ratio. How do I do this?

css:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 5px;

}

.grid-item {
    background-color: orange;
    border: solid;

}
```

html:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need your grid items to span their place in the grid. As long as the browsersupport for aspect-ratio is not complete, you could use the padding-trick:

```
.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  display: flow-root;

  &:before {
    content: '';
    float: left;
    padding-top: 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. This solves the problem however it then creates a new one. That's my bad, I should have shared the rest of the code but did not think it would matter much.
Here is the full class:
```
.grid-container {
    margin: 20px;
    height: 700px;
    overflow: auto;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
```
maybe you could check this code out and resize your window because it's hard to explain what is happening

Comment: I think it might be wise not to use a height for your grid - height must change when width changes. At least, when you want to keep the aspect ratio ;) Is that he new problem?

Comment: I just tested. All I found was the height issue ...

Comment: ahh i see what is happening now. The thing is I want the container to be a certain height and if there are too many items in it (which eventually will be added) I want overflow to be auto. The problem here is that somehow the aspect ratio is kept only while all items combined overflow the container height. Once all items fit the container height only their width gets resized and the aspect ratio is not kept

Comment: Pure geometrics dictate that you can either keep your aspect ratio OR have a fixed height. You cannot have both, I'm afraid ... :)